# tar --exclude flag not excluding the directory if I add the '/' at the end of the path

Tags: linux, bash, tar

if I use this command:

```
sudo tar -zcvpf exclusion.tar.gz mybkup/ --exclude=mybkup/etc/ssh/
```

then If I try to see if the ssh directory is included in the tarball contents I see that in fact is included:

```
[user@smashingx1 ~]$ tar -tvzf exclusion.tar.gz | grep ssh
lrwxrwxrwx user/user         0 2016-11-30 04:26 mybkup/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/sshd.service -> /usr/lib/systemd/system/sshd.service
-rw-r----- user/user       506 2016-11-30 04:26 mybkup/etc/sysconfig/sshd
-rw-r--r-- user/user      5996 2016-11-30 04:26 mybkup/etc/xdg/autostart/gnome-keyring-ssh.desktop
drwxr-xr-x user/user         0 2016-11-30 04:26 mybkup/etc/ssh/
-rw-r--r-- user/user    242153 2016-11-30 04:26 mybkup/etc/ssh/moduli
-rw-r--r-- user/user      2208 2016-11-30 04:26 mybkup/etc/ssh/ssh_config
-rw-r--r-- user/user       382 2016-11-30 04:26 mybkup/etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key.pub
-rw-r--r-- user/user       162 2016-11-30 04:26 mybkup/etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key.pub
-rw-r--r-- user/user      4760 2016-11-30 04:26 mybkup/etc/ssh/sshd_config
-rw-r--r-- user/user        82 2016-11-30 04:26 mybkup/etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key.pub
-rw-r----- user/user      1675 2016-11-30 04:26 mybkup/etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
-rw-r----- user/user       227 2016-11-30 04:26 mybkup/etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
-rw------- user/user      4361 2016-11-30 04:26 mybkup/etc/ssh/sshd_config.rpmnew
-rw-r----- user/user       387 2016-11-30 04:26 mybkup/etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key
-rw-r--r-- user/user      8730 2016-11-30 04:26 mybkup/etc/selinux/targeted/modules/active/modules/rssh.pp
-rw-r--r-- user/user     18774 2016-11-30 04:26 mybkup/etc/selinux/targeted/modules/active/modules/ssh.pp
-rw-r--r-- user/user       904 2016-11-30 04:26 mybkup/etc/pam.d/sshd
```

but if I dont add the last '/' at the end of the directory path now it excludes the directory:

```
sudo tar -zcvpf exclusion.tar.gz mybkup/ --exclude=mybkup/etc/ssh

tar -tvzf exclusion.tar.gz | grep ssh

lrwxrwxrwx user/user         0 2016-11-30 04:26 mybkup/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/sshd.service -> /usr/lib/systemd/system/sshd.service
-rw-r----- user/user       506 2016-11-30 04:26 mybkup/etc/sysconfig/sshd
-rw-r--r-- user/user      5996 2016-11-30 04:26 mybkup/etc/xdg/autostart/gnome-keyring-ssh.desktop
-rw-r--r-- user/user      8730 2016-11-30 04:26 mybkup/etc/selinux/targeted/modules/active/modules/rssh.pp
-rw-r--r-- user/user     18774 2016-11-30 04:26 mybkup/etc/selinux/targeted/modules/active/modules/ssh.pp
-rw-r--r-- user/user       904 2016-11-30 04:26 mybkup/etc/pam.d/sshd
```

I am confused because I thought that by instructing tar to exclude the directory, it would exclude the directory and its contents, but apparently is not the case, can somebody explain please?

Comment: Directory names don't end in `/`. It's just a convention that we use for readability. You will notice that `tar` saves the directory as `mybkup/etc/sysconfig/sshd` instead of `mybkup/etc/sysconfig/sshd/`. When tar compares `sshd == sshd/`, obviously they are not equal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, a quick tip. You can test the behavior easier without actually creating a tar file, like this:

```
tar c mybkup/ --exclude=mybkup/etc/ssh/ | tar t
```

I hope you can appreciate the beauty in that.

The exclude pattern definition is very primitive.
And sadly, `man tar` doesn't explain anything about how "PATTERN" should be written and how it is interpreted.

Based on some observations, I came up with the following reasoning.
In your example, `mybkup/etc/ssh/` is not excluded because it is neither a file nor a directory. Although `mybkup/etc/ssh` is a directory, but `mybkup/etc/ssh/` is not. In other words, the trailing `/` is not part of the name of the directory, and so it's not treated as a directory, and therefore simply ignored, not excluded.

I'm afraid that's just the way it is. This is such a primitive feature.

Shell globs are ok though. For example, given your files, if you do this:

```
tar c mybkup --exclude='mybkup/etc/sy*' | tar t
```

It will exclude `mybkup/etc/systemd` and `mybkup/etc/sysconfig` directories and their contents. (Note that it's important to quote `mybkup/etc/sy*` so that `tar` will interpret the `*` instead of the shell.)

Answer (score 0):

--exclude=PATTERN

exclude files, given as a PATTERN

when you use --exclude=mybackup/etc/ssh/ tar doesn't get any exact match of the patter. and when you use --exclude=mybackup/etc/ssh tar get exact match of the patter.

Comment: well I think I noticed that just by looking at the output, but the question is why? the directory is called ssh/, why it doesn't get any exact match of the pattern?